# Switching data in text file to ASCII or to UTF8

Tags: file, unix, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a text file in Unix with two columns that contains strings in various languages (Chines, Korean, Japaneese, Arabic, English, French, German, Etc...) in the first column.

Current file's encoding is:

> > *file index.txt* 
>   index.txt: Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text, with LF, NEL line
>   terminators

I've been told that this file have a subset of entries (in column 1) that using a non-ASCII, non-UTF8 encoding and that I should switching data in this column preferably to ASCII. If not possible, to UTF8.

For example: 
1. How user see it: 'Bibliothe`<C3>`que'.
2. Via `vim`: 'BibliothÃ¨que'.
3. Via less: 'Bibliothèque'.

I already tried many conversion and method (for days) but non of them convert it as expected.

E.g
I tried to change the encoding to UTF8:

> iconv -f CP1256 -t UTF-8 < index.txt > index.txt.2 
>   770> file index.txt.2 
>   index.txt.2: UTF-8 Unicode English text But the characters
>   seems to be corrupted in the new file.

But got: 1. Via vim: 'Bibliothﺃ¨que' 2. Via less: 'Bibliothأ¨que'.

I check how many non-ASCii rows this file contains and got output file with hundreds lines in the file 'index.txt.non_ascii':

> pcregrep --color='auto' -n "[\x80-\xFF]" index.txt > index.txt.non_ascii

I also tried to write a short script (in Perl) that read the data and store it as utf8, but strings where corrupted again.

I will really appreciate if someone could assist me with this problem.

Thanks in advance!
Mike

Comment: I just tried to do that using notepadd++ (copy-paste into new utf-8 file). and it seems to be ok now. I sent it to our user/supplier for verification. Thanks!

Comment: `file` doesn't tell you the character encoding of a text file. It tells you one possibility. Only the author, spec, etc, can tell you.